# remove key and values from array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to remove or delete all object where inspectionScheduleQuestionId is null , how do we address this in JS ?

Thanks.

#data

```
const data = [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "inspectionScheduleQuestionId": 1,
        "inspectionScheduleConfirmationId": 0,
        "description": "65"
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "inspectionScheduleQuestionId": 10,
        "inspectionScheduleConfirmationId": 0,
        "description": "656"
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "inspectionScheduleQuestionId": null,
        "inspectionScheduleConfirmationId": 0,
        "description": 6
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "inspectionScheduleQuestionId": null,
        "inspectionScheduleConfirmationId": 0,
        "description": 21
    },

]
```

Comment: What have you attempted to address this? SO isn't a coding service.

Comment: sorry forgot to add , adding it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` for this:

```
const updatedData = data.filter(item => item.inspectionScheduleQuestionId !== null);
```

[Here's some more information on `Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 0):

```
new data = data.filter(d => d.inspectionScheduleQuestionId)
```